# Find a running process which changes the location path and the windowname

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find whenever a certain process is running (not my process).

- But there's problem...the process is changing the
  name, windowname, path everytime it runs and it doesn't have external dlls.

Is there any other way of finding the process beside looking for the window name,path,name,hash of process?

1. PS: I need to do this with at least 60 different processes ...
2. PS: Looking by the windowclass name won't help because there are
   plenty of windows processes which may use the same windowclass name.

Comment: How do you identify this process ? Does it do something ?

Comment: The process modifies the memory of another application , so the "other application" will do whatever the process wants to

Comment: A process doesn't fall from the sky.  It has a name and a very specific startup EXE, Process.Name and Process.Modules.  If that's not enough then you just don't know enough about it.

Comment: So you're looking to write a program that defeats a virus or trojan horse, or similar? Seems to me that you should just run a virus scanner and get rid of that dangerous app.

Comment: Nope, just a way to defend against botters in a mmorpg game

Comment: First of all find a pattern. Only you can do that. When you've done that you'll have your answer. Are you seriously expecting us to find the pattern?

Answer (score 0):

If it has some portion of repeating name then you can use. Or do you want to load DLL at runtime.

```
static bool CheckIfProcessRunning(string someCommonRepeatingPortionName)
{
    return Process.GetProcesses().Any(
        p => p.ProcessName.Contains(someCommonRepeatingPortionName));
}
```